# Adding a second address to Moderncv

Tags: moderncv, addresses

I am trying to add a second address line to the moderncv template, specifically for the casual style. I know this has been somewhat asked about before, but I have not been able to make any of the old answers work with the new moderncv published in July 2015. The only changes I have made to the template were to add in code to create the second address, and I commented out the photo for convenience. When I compile, I get

> ! File ended while scanning use of \@argdef.\par<>
>   template.texI suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing meto read past
>   where you wanted me to stop. . . .

Here is my .tex file:

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2015 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'banking', 'oldstyle' and 'fancy'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'black', 'blue' (default), 'burgundy', 'green', 'grey', 'orange', 'purple' and 'red'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CODE FOR A SECOND ADDRESS IN THE INFO BLOCK
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addresstwo}[3]{\def\@addressstreettwo{#1}\def\@addresscitytwo{#2}\def\@addresscountrytwo{#3}}
\renewcommand*{\makecvfoot}{%
  \recomputecvfootlengths{}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox[b]{\footwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \color{color2}\addressfont%
        \vspace{\baselineskip}% forces a white line to ensure space between main text and footer (as footer height can't be known in advance)
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofoot[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreettwo}}{}{\addtofoot[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreettwo}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscitytwo}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscitytwo}}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountrytwo}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscountrytwo}}%
          \flushfoot\@firstfootelementtrue\\}%
        \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
          \addtofoot{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofoot{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofoot{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
        \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
          \addtofoot{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofoot{\@extrainfo}}%
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\footboxwidth=0pt}}{}{\flushfoot}% the lengthtest is required to avoid flushing an empty footer, which could cause a blank line due to the \\ after the address, if no other personal info is used
        }}}%
  \pagestyle{plain}}
\makeatother




% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\addresstwo{street and number two}{postcode city two}{country two}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty

\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the optional "type" of the phone can be "mobile" (default), "fixed" or "fax"
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[github]{jdoe}                              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% bibliography adjustements (only useful if you make citations in your resume, or print a list of publications using BibTeX)
%   to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels)
\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
%   to redefine the bibliography heading string ("Publications")
%\renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5\cite{book1}}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}

% Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib
%  for numerical labels: \renewcommand{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}% CONSIDER MERGING WITH PREAMBLE PART
%  to redefine the heading string ("Publications"): \renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                        % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

% Publications from a BibTeX file using the multibib package
%\section{Publications}
%\nocitebook{book1,book2}
%\bibliographystylebook{plain}
%\bibliographybook{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
%\nocitemisc{misc1,misc2,misc3}
%\bibliographystylemisc{plain}
%\bibliographymisc{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\clearpage
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}          % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]

\makeletterclosing

%\clearpage\end{CJK*}                              % if you are typesetting your resume in Chinese using CJK; the \clearpage is required for fancyhdr to work correctly with CJK, though it kills the page numbering by making \lastpage undefined
\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have only one missing `}` in your code and a missing command `\flushfoot` to start the second address in a new line.  Please see the following MWE (changes marked with `<========`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{casual} % \moderncvhead[\moderncvstyleheadoptions]{1}
                       % \moderncvbody{1}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}  % \rmdefault 
%\nopagenumbers{} 

% character encoding
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CODE FOR A SECOND ADDRESS IN THE INFO BLOCK
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addresstwo}[3]{\def\@addressstreettwo{#1}\def\@addresscitytwo{#2}\def\@addresscountrytwo{#3}}

\renewcommand*{\makecvfoot}{%
  \recomputecvfootlengths{}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox[b]{\footwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \color{color2}\addressfont%
        \vspace{\baselineskip}% forces a white line to ensure space between main text and footer (as footer height can't be known in advance)
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofoot[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscountry}\flushfoot\\}% <========================================================
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreettwo}}{}{\addtofoot[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreettwo}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscitytwo}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscitytwo}}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountrytwo}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscountrytwo}}%
          \flushfoot\@firstfootelementtrue\\}}% <=======================
        \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
          \addtofoot{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofoot{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofoot{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
        \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
          \addtofoot{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofoot{\@extrainfo}}%
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\footboxwidth=0pt}}{}{\flushfoot}% the lengthtest is required to avoid flushing an empty footer, which could cause a blank line due to the \\ after the address, if no other personal info is used
        }}}%
  \pagestyle{plain}}
\makeatother




% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\addresstwo{street and number two}{postcode city two}{country two}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty

\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the optional "type" of the phone can be "mobile" (default), "fixed" or "fax"
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[github]{jdoe}                              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% bibliography adjustements (only useful if you make citations in your resume, or print a list of publications using BibTeX)
%   to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels)
\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
%   to redefine the bibliography heading string ("Publications")
%\renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}%\cite{book1}}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}


\end{document}
```

and see the result:

[image: page 1 of mwe]

**Update:**

In the code above is mentioned, that allways two addresses are there.

If that is not true, we have to change the code a little bit ...

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}% <========================================================
```

In this line we can delete the added `\flushfoot\\`.

The next line tests if you have defined `\addresstwo`.  Now if it is undefinded (sic!) we need to call `\flushfoot\@firstfootelementtrue\\` to end the first and one address line. I added it.  Then we had to add the deleted `\flushfoot\\` to end the line for the first address before starting writing the second.

```
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreettwo}}{\flushfoot\@firstfootelementtrue\\}{\flushfoot\\\addtofoot[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreettwo}%
%                                             ^================================^  ^=========^
```

The other code stays unchanged.  Now you can choos if you need or not the second address.

Complete updated MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % version 2.0.0

\moderncvstyle{casual} % \moderncvhead[\moderncvstyleheadoptions]{1}
                       % \moderncvbody{1}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}  % \rmdefault 
%\nopagenumbers{} 

% character encoding
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}

\moderncvicons{marvosym} % marvosym awesome % for pdflatex! <===========
\setlength{\footskip}{78pt} % no more \footskip warning <===============


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CODE FOR A SECOND ADDRESS IN THE INFO BLOCK
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addresstwo}[3]{\def\@addressstreettwo{#1}\def\@addresscitytwo{#2}\def\@addresscountrytwo{#3}}

\renewcommand*{\makecvfoot}{%
  \recomputecvfootlengths{}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox[b]{\footwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \color{color2}\addressfont%
        \vspace{\baselineskip}% forces a white line to ensure space between main text and footer (as footer height can't be known in advance)
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofoot[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}% <========================================================
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreettwo}}{\flushfoot\@firstfootelementtrue\\}{\flushfoot\\\addtofoot[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreettwo}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscitytwo}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscitytwo}}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountrytwo}{}}{}{\addtofoot[~--~]{\@addresscountrytwo}}%
          \flushfoot\@firstfootelementtrue\\}}% <=======================
        \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
          \addtofoot{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofoot{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofoot{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
        \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
          \addtofoot{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofoot{\@extrainfo}}%
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\footboxwidth=0pt}}{}{\flushfoot}% the lengthtest is required to avoid flushing an empty footer, which could cause a blank line due to the \\ after the address, if no other personal info is used
        }}}%
  \pagestyle{plain}}
\makeatother




% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% 
%\addresstwo{street and number two}{postcode city two}{country two}% 

\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890} 
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org} 
\homepage{www.johndoe.com} 
\social[linkedin]{john.doe} 
\social[twitter]{jdoe} 
\social[github]{jdoe} 
\extrainfo{additional information}
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote}

% bibliography adjustements (only useful if you make citations in your resume, or print a list of publications using BibTeX)
%   to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels)
\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
%   to redefine the bibliography heading string ("Publications")
%\renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\clearpage
\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}%\cite{book1}}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, and thank you for the reasoning in the explanation. I very much appreciate it.